# How to make a case when better in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `stored procedure` in which I have 2 variables

```
Declare @from int
Declare @to int
```

This variables will give the month from and to for a math calculation.

My table is like this:

Sum1 / Sum2 / Sum3 / Sum4 / Sum5 / Sum6 / Sum7 / Sum8 / Sum9 / Sum 10 / Sum 11 / Sum 12 / GroupByID

And I have calculation in my SQL like this:

```
Select SUM( SUM1) + SUm(Sum2) + .... + Sum(Sum12) from Table group by GroupByID
```

Now I only want the `Sum(month)` of a month which is given by the `parameters`, how to do this?

Comment: This is really a poor design

Comment: Not from me... comes from a webservice from SAP, I only have to handle this

Comment: Which dbms? (Doesn't look like ANSI SQL...)

Comment: @jarlh - Declare statement looks like `Sql-Server`

Comment: How do you know which years the months apply to? What happens if the from month is *after* the to month?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `Dynamic Query`

```
DECLARE @from INT=1
DECLARE @to  INT=5,
        @cnt INT,
        @sql NVARCHAR(max)

SET @cnt=@from
SET @sql='select '

WHILE @cnt <= @to
  BEGIN
      SET @sql += 'sum(sum' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @cnt) + '),'
      SET @cnt+=1
  END

SELECT @sql = LEFT(@sql, Len(@sql)-1)+ ' from tablename group by GroupByID'

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: Just a little comment: you can remove one variable `@from` and assign 1 to `@cnt`

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri - It won't be always `1`. It is a input.

Comment: Then use `@from` instead of `@cnt`.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri - Just don't want to override the Input parameter thats all

Answer (score 0):

You will have to check @to and @from for each month and apply the related month column to the sum expression if in the range:

```
Select 
  GroupByID,
  SUM(
    case when  1 between @to and @from then coalesce(Sum1,0)  else 0 end +
    case when  2 between @to and @from then coalesce(Sum2,0)  else 0 end +
    case when  3 between @to and @from then coalesce(Sum3,0)  else 0 end +
    case when  4 between @to and @from then coalesce(Sum4,0)  else 0 end +
    case when  5 between @to and @from then coalesce(Sum5,0)  else 0 end +
    case when  6 between @to and @from then coalesce(Sum6,0)  else 0 end +
    case when  7 between @to and @from then coalesce(Sum7,0)  else 0 end +
    case when  8 between @to and @from then coalesce(Sum8,0)  else 0 end +
    case when  9 between @to and @from then coalesce(Sum9,0)  else 0 end +
    case when 10 between @to and @from then coalesce(Sum10,0) else 0 end +
    case when 11 between @to and @from then coalesce(Sum11,0) else 0 end +
    case when 12 between @to and @from then coalesce(Sum12,0) else 0 end
    ) as total
from Table
group by GroupByID;
```